# Installing, configuring and using PHP Xdebug on remote shared server

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

After installing PHP XDebug plugin for VSCode and setting up Xdebug configuration on the shared (dev) server, Xdebug seems to be running but does not stop at breakpoints.

What can cause this?

Comment: Port in use cleared. Also, XDebug cross-runs between users, i.e. showing an exception of another user.

Comment: *"What can cause this?"* -- Wrong config. 1) *"...on the shared (dev) server..."* and 2) *"Also, XDebug cross-runs between users, i.e. showing an exception of another user."* You most likely will have to use **DBGp Proxy** if you have more than 1 dev debugging the same code on the same server (remember: it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around). You could try to configure Xdebug to detect the IP address from the request, but if this is a publicly reachable server then it will be insecure (as anyone can initiate the debug session then...)

Comment: This is for PhpStorm, but you can still read the article and adapt it to VSCode: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/multiuser-debugging-via-xdebug-proxies.html 2) https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgpProxy

Comment: Not the same code, everyone's code is in a different directory, but the same server and the same XDebug.

Comment: It's the "same server and the same Xdebug" that is the problem then. As @LazyOne says, you need to use the DBGp proxy (or Xdebug Cloud).